# Popping multiple levels in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to be able to pop multiple views from a UITableViewController stack.  For example in the Apple DrillDownSave example, when viewing Level 3 to go back to Level 1 or when viewing an Item to go back to Level 2 when a button is pushed.

I tried:

```
[self.navigationController.parentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];  
[self.navigationController.parentViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

but these leave me the same place as just a single popViewControllerAnimated:.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to send `popToViewController: animated:` to the navigation controller. You can use the navigation controller's `viewControllers` property to figure out which view controller it is that you want to pop to.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you Giao that did it.  I changed my code to:

```
NSArray *allViewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
NSInteger n = [allViewControllers count];
[self.navigationController popToViewController: [allViewControllers objectAtIndex: (n-3)] animated: YES];
```

and it works perfectly.