# How to go to navigation controller from two levels up view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have navigation controller which is the initial view controller.

The order is like this:

> main navigation vc --->  vc1  --->  vc2

I want to go like this:

> main navigation vc --->  vc1  --->  vc2  --->  main navigation vc

and I want to remove vc1 and vc2 from the hierarchy.

What is the preferred to do this?

Using segues I can do this, but I dont want to go back to vc1 or vc2, I wanna remove them from memory as well.

Comment: am I correct in assuming that popToRootViewController doesn't work for you because it produces wrong animation?

Comment: yeah it worked perfectly ! what i wanted.. seems to free up the memory as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2615999/4475605

Comment: this is swift solution:  `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`